# Не работает If/elif/else Python

Tags: python

Только учусь, так что код очень корявый. Решил написать игру блэкджэк(21, очко, какие ещё у неё названия есть). И вот у меня есть условие где игрок должен решить, брать карту или нет. Но почему-то если я выбираю нет, программа всё равно выдаёт мне карту. Выдаёт даже если я ответил, вообще другими словами, хотя в else написал, чтобы программа выдавала вопрос. Уже который день пытаюсь исправить. Добавил скриншоты кода. [image: Если хочет взять]

[image: Если не хочет]

Comment: добавьте код с минимально воспроизводимым примером в вопрос, а не скриншоты

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if choise == 'N' or choise == 'n':
```

Comment: Заработало! Спасибо огромное! Что-то я очень сильно сглупил)

Answer (score 3):

Сам вопрос, конечно, дубликат, и ответ уже есть, но вообще в данном конкретном случае лучше приводить ответ к какому-то одному регистру и тогда уже проверять:

```
if choise.upper() == 'N':
```